# Python division doesn't work as expected for large numbers

Tags: python, largenumber

I have three variables `a`, `b` and `c`. I want to make sure that after doing this:

```
c -= a*b
```

`c` is not negative.

I am doing this for now:

```
if a*b > c:
      b = c // a
```

but for very large numbers, I still get negative value in `c`. what should I do?

To reproduce the error here are some sample numbers:

a = 5.195497498518083

b = 1.0813434626413702e+16

c = 5.614533816817397e+16

Comment: Please create a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Maybe try `if c - a*b >= 0:` although it doesnt answer your question as to why large numbers fail. It may even hide it.

Comment: `c = max(0, c - a * b)`…?

Comment: None of the comments answered my questions. I don't want to set c explicitly. I want to ensure that b is not big enough such that b*a is greater than c.

Comment: You're working with floating point numbers which are very close together. Yes, due to floating point inaccuracies, you may end up with numbers slightly lower than 0 when doing any such close arithmetic. It would help to provide more context here to find an appropriate solution. Why won't `max(0, ...)` be acceptable for instance?

Comment: @deceze I cannot set `c` because it represents the budget and `a` is the price of an item and `b` is the number of units. I want to make sure that the number of units are not large enough so that the entire cost is larger than the budget. One solution could be to have while loop but it will be very slow.

Comment: what you are calculating is `c-a*(c/a)` that is very close to 0 and due to rounding you can  get on either side of 0. use integers that are 100*float_val and work in cents, with BigInts (standard in Python) you can represents any big number exact

Comment: If you're dealing with money / currency you should not be working with floats at all.

Comment: `a * b > c` gives `True` in the example you provided. What is unexpected about the behavior?

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, this might not be related to the how large the numbers are, but to the fact you are working with `float`, and there are [limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html). To illustrate the problem, check this in your REPL.

```
>>> a=0.1+0.2
>>> b=0.3
>>> a==b
False
>>> a
0.30000000000000004
>>>
```

But you could try and work with integers as suggested by @rioV8

Comment: But `a * b == a * b` for floats. I think the issue is something else, especially since `a * b > c` is True in OP's example.

Comment: @MadPhysicist but dividing and then multiplying again might not give the same result with floats, that's the problem with OP's example, they calculated b as `c // a` and then are expecting for `a*b` to equal `c` which might not stand with floating point numbers.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat. Agreed, especially with the truncating division